# ios phonegap ) where should I location custom push notification sound?

Tags: ios, cordova

I found out I need to put my custom notification file to xcode project but I am not sure where to..

where should I put my notification sound?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file has to be named `beep.wav` and placed right in the `www` folder.

From the [Cordova Docs](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_notification_notification.md.html#notification.beep):

> - There is no native beep API for iPhone.
>
>   - Cordova implements beep by playing an audio file via the
>       media API.
>   - The user must provide a file with the desired beep tone.
>   - **This file must be less than 30 seconds long, located in the www/
>       root, and must be named beep.wav.**

Comment: But the Pushplugin docs say differently https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin#ecb-amazon-fire-os-android-and-ios

Comment: See the date on my answer, it's from almost two years ago, so it might be a bit outdated.

Answer (score 0):

Custom notification sound can be named anything you like and put the .wav file into your Resources folder in the xcode project. Then specify the name in the payload of your push notification.