# Cordova Phonegap local notification sound on iOS

Tags: android, ios, cordova, notifications

I'm trying to test the local notifications on iOS using Cordova.

Everything it's working fine except the sound, I only get the default notification sound, not the custom sound I've added in the options.

This is only happening on **iOS**.

**Code:**

```
var now = new Date().getTime(),
    _10_seconds_from_now = new Date(now + 3*1000);

window.plugin.notification.local.add({
            id:      1,
            title:   'Reminder',
            message: 'Dont forget to buy some flowers.',
            repeat:  'weekly',
            date:    _10_seconds_from_now,
            sound:  'www/alarms/burglar.caf'
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, after a few looks in the objective-c code I finally made it work!

The solution it's very simple, but not documented anywhere.  You have to put the prefix file:// and all will work.
**sound:    'file://alarms/factory.wav'**

Example:

```
window.plugin.notification.local.add({
            id:      2,
            title:   'Reminder',
            message: 'Dont forget to buy some flowers blah blah blah.',
            repeat:  'weekly',
            date:    _10_seconds_from_now,
            sound:  'file://alarms/factory.wav'
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

[API](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/#notification-sound-on-android) says:

**Notification sound on iOS**

**Note:** Custom sounds must be under **30 seconds** when played. If a custom sound is over that limit, the default system sound is played instead.

This [selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13344035/ios-phonegap-where-should-i-location-custom-push-notification-sound) answer suggested:

From the [Cordova Docs](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_notification_notification.md.html#notification.beep):

- Cordova implements beep by playing an audio file via the media API.
- The user must provide a file with the desired beep tone.
- This file must be less than 30 seconds long, located in the `www/` root, and **must be named beep.wav**

Comment: This is for Android, but I'm trying on an iPhone

Comment: this might be the reason

Answer (score 2):

I also faced that problem you can use this code as i applied and it's working fine for me

[cordova local notification sound not working in ios and andorid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31341856/cordova-local-notification-sound-not-working-in-ios-and-andorid)

open the link I think it will help to you