# cordova local notification sound not working in ios and Android

Tags: android, ios, cordova, sencha-touch, localnotification

I am using [`cordova-plugin-local-notifications`](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications)
plugin. Now I have issue to get my sound file in both Android and iOS.

```
window.plugin.notification.local.add({
    id:         '0001',   
    date:       new Date,      
    message:    'hello',
    title:      'title',  
    badge:      1,
    sound:      'www/resources/audio/beep.mp3', 
    autoCancel: true, 
    ongoing:    true 
});
```

What I need to do I need to change in native side my app in sencha touch.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the plugin is updated and the `"window.plugin.notification.local.add"` method is deprecated now, now it is `"window.plugin.notification.local.schedule"`, the "date" is now "at" and "message" is now "text".

To install plugin use below command:

```
cordova plugin add de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification && cordova prepare
```

I have a plugin version installed: 0.8.1, before it is 0.7.4 at my end.

Set "sound" as like below:

```
sound: "file://resources/audio/beep.mp3"
```

so your new method will be like below:

```
window.plugin.notification.local.schedule({
    id:         '0001',
    at:         new Date,
    text:       'hello',
    title:      'title',
    badge:      1,
    sound:      'file://resources/audio/beep.mp3',
    autoCancel: true,
    ongoing:    true
});
```

It is working fine for me on iOS and Android devices.
Hope it will be helpful to you :)

Comment: Thank - you very much sir . I have applied code given by you and change plugin as you suggested now it's working fine for me 

I hope it will help to others

Comment: HI Ravi, Im having the same issue, and my code is quite simple, any ideas why there would be popups and yet no sound?

window.plugin.notification.local.schedule({
          id: 1,
          title: "Title",
          text: "Your location has changed",
          sound: "file://sound/notification.caf"
});

Comment: @Rohit, what version of `cordova`, `cordova-ios`, `cordova-android` and `iOS` are you using? I can get sound working on Android and iOS emulator but not on iPhone running iOS 9.3.1